# Failed JMockit Tests on @EJB with constant lookup

Tags: jmockit

In the path of an @Tested class in a JMockit Test there has been an @EJB(lookup="somebeanname") on an interface that has caused all tests to fail since they can not @Injectable in the test case.

Does anyone have a suggestion or run into this? Our workaround has been deencapsulating this; however, I am hopping that some annotation will be a better solution.

```
public class TestClass {
    @Tested ValidatorClass validator;
    @Injectable StaticAPILookup staticItem;

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        Object objToValidate = new Object(); //Assume something here to do work on
        Object results = validator.doWork(objToValidate)
    }
}

public class ValidatorClass {
    @EJB (lookup="jndiLookString")
    private StaticAPILookup staticItem;

    public Object doWork(Object someObject) {
        ---code in here is not important  
    }
}
```

Comment: Show an example test.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the `@Injectable` field (or parameter) should match the name specified in the Java EE annotation (ie, `@Injectable TypeToInject someBeanName` for `@EJB(lookup="someBeanName")`), not the name of the target field (it would be if no name was specified there, for example when using `@Inject`). This is mentioned in the API documentation for `@Tested`.